# Van't Hoff Factor of Sucrose

Tags: physical-chemistry, solutions

What is the Van't Hoff factor for sucrose?
According to me it should be 2 as sucrose is a disaccharide.

Comment: So what? Salts have factors like 2 or 3 because they **dissociate** into that many particles. Does sucrose dissociate? No.

Answer (score 2):

Sucrose is a organic molecule. It doesnt show any dissociation in water and hence its van't hoff factor is 1.

Moreover disaccharide is the sugar formed when two monosaccharides (simple sugars) are joined by glycosidic linkage. Glycosidic linkage would **never** break on **simply dissolving** it in water. So how are you expecting van't hoff factor to be 2 ?